# dynamic ipBlock() 's in Widget

Tags: php, impresspages

I want to create a simple Bootstrap Jumbotron Widget with a ipBlock inside, where users can add other widgets. Their might be multiple jumbotron widgets on a single page. What is the best way to create a dynamic ipBlock allocation like:

```
<?php echo ipBlock($dynamicBlock)->exampleContent('') ?>
```

Thanks in advance!
-Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the columns plugin and do in the same fashion

http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/NestedColumns

Comment: Thanks, i made it work with your tip and by looking at the AccordionAndTabs plugin.